# Is it inefficient to use a large number of closures?

Tags: javascript, performance

My webapp has an undo/redo concept.  I am considering how best to implement it.

My current approach is to have an array of arrays where each array is a bunch of callbacks to invoke to restore that version.  E.g. for a label to restore its old value would be:

```
var undoer = {
    at = 0,
    stack = [[]],
    push = function(do,undo) {
        if(undoer.at > 0) {
            undoer.splice(0,undoer.at,[]);
            undoer.at = 0;
        }
        undoer.stack[0].push([do,undo]);
    },
    commit = function() { 
        if(undoer.at == 0 && undoer.stack[0])
            stack.unshift([]);
    },
    rollback = function() {
        if(undoer.at == 0 && undoer.stack[0])
            while(var func: stack[0].pop())
                func[1]();
    },
    undo = function() {
        // move the at index back, call all the undos
    ...
    redo = function() {
        // move the at index forward, call al dos
    ...
};

function Label(text) {
    var _text = text,
        label = {
            get: function() { return _text; },
            set: function(text) {
                var old = text;
                _text = text;
                undoer.push(
                    function() { _text = text; }, // do
                    function() { _text = old; } // undo
                );
            },
            ...
    };
    return label;
}
```

(apologies for typos and omissions in this pseudocode)

This is storing the state changes needed to undo and redo a change in closures.

Imagine now many thousands of edits.  Would it be more memory efficient to instead use variadic functions and put copies of the `arguments` into the undo stack?

And are there better ways to do undo/redo?

Answer (score 1):

yep.

but they're easier to read/use/maintain.  no "right" answer, just cost/benefit analysis.  just make sure you're not going to recurse too deeply.